# MSSQL agent: Failed notification if 0 rows exported

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am running a daily job in MSSQL agent, that runs a package to export a certain table to an excel file. After completion it sends me an email.

It happened couple of times that the table was empty and it exported 0 rows.
I did not receive a job failed notification, because the job didn't fail.

I would like to receive a failed notification when it's exporting 0 rows.

How would you achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: First, this is far too vague to be answered. Also, do you really want a failure if there are zero rows, or do you just want to receive a different notification? Or does an empty table imply that there is an upstream issue that needs to be addressed in real time?

Comment: Write stored procured on the destination table and check whether the job loaded any records on today's date and send a notification when the value becomes zero.

Comment: @Eric Brandt, Yes, indeed. if it's exporting 0 rows that means there was some problem. If it would send me a different notification would also be good, but makes no difference, since when it's failed I will check the issue anyway.

Comment: @Bhasyakarulu Kottakota, Thanks! I will check into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to force a package to return a failure (which will then cause the calling Agent job to report a failure).

One simple way would be to put a `Row Count` task between the source and destination in the data flow task that populates the spreadsheet. Assign the value to a variable, say @RowsExported.

Back on the `Control Flow` tab, if there's more to the package, put a condition on the precedent constraint leading to the rest of the work where `@RowsExported > 0` so the rest of the package will only continue if there were rows sent. Whether or not there's more to the package, add a new precedent constraint coming off the data flow with a condition `@RowsExported == 0`. Send that constraint to an `Execute SQL` task that just contains the script `SELECT 1/0;`.

Now, if zero rows are exported, the package will throw a division by zero error, and the calling job will fail.

There are other ways, of course, but this one can be implemented very quickly.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you very much!